# Setting the Content Type Uploading Photos to S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload photos to my S3 bucket.  The file being uploaded is making it to my S3 bucket successfully.  The problem?  Yup, it is in the form of 'application/octet-stream' though.  Given the implementation below, what changes do I need to make and where?

index.php

```
<?php
require 's3.php';

$s3 = new S3('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID','AWS_SECRET KEY', 'region: us-west-2');

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $name = $file['name'];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        var_dump($tmp_name);

        $extension = explode('.', $name);
        $extension = strtolower(end($extension));
        // var_dump($extension);

        $key = md5(uniqid());
        $tmp_file_name = "{$key}.{$extension}";
        $tmp_file_path = "files/{$tmp_file_name}";

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $tmp_file_path);

        try{
            S3::putObject(
            $tmp_file_path,
            'mazzo-php-app',
            $tmp_file_name,
            S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
            array(),
            array() 
            );
            unlink($tmp_file_path);
        } catch(S3Exception $e){
            die("There was an error uploading the file.");
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

s3.php

```
// Content-Type
if (!isset($input['type']))
        {
            if (isset($requestHeaders['Content-Type']))
                $input['type'] =& $requestHeaders['Content-Type'];
            elseif (isset($input['file']))
                $input['type'] = self::__getMIMEType($input['file']);
            else
                $input['type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
        }
```

Comment: Which version of the PHP SDK are you using?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: ^3.133

Answer (score 1):

The [`putObject()` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) shows a `ContentType` field:

```php
$result = $client->putObject([
    'ACL' => 'private|public-read|public-read-write|authenticated-read|aws-exec-read|bucket-owner-read|bucket-owner-full-control',
    'Body' => <string || resource || Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface>,
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'ContentType' => '<string>',
    ...
]);
```

> **ContentType:** A standard MIME type describing the format of the contents.

Comment: I said using my implementation.

Comment: I was struggling with this exact thing and the `ContentType` field solved it for me. Thanks :)